# Цитирование комментариев

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Собственно сабж, как реализовать цитирование определённого ответа?

как я понимаю, надо выдернуть строку одного из ответов/комментариев и вставить её в textarea, вопрос реализации сего чуда. гугл 2 страницы не помогло(

примерно логику представляю, но не понимаю как реализовать. если с метками где ошибся - предполагаю что можно реализовать всеми 3-мя способами.

UPD

```
<table width="100%" border=0>
    <tr>
        <td width="5"><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" height="58" border="0"></td>
        <td background="/img/spacer.gif" class="ctitle" valign="top" colspan="2">
        #<?echo $n ?> написал: <? echo $res['autor']; ?> (<? echo $date; ?>)</td>
        <td width="5"><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" height="58" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td background="/img/spacer.gif"><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" border="0"></td>
        <td valign="top" colspan="2">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="140" valign="top" border=1 style="color: #717171;font-size: 11px;font-family: tahoma;"><img src="" border="0" /><br />
        <img width="100" height="20" src="<?echo $usergroupico;?>" /><br /><br />Группа: <? echo $usergroup; ?><br />Регистрация: </td>
        <td class="your_comment_container" valign="top"><? echo $res['message']; ?><br /><br />
        --------------------<br /><div style="color: #717171;font-size: 11px;font-family: tahoma;"><? echo $signature; ?></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </td>
        <td background="/img/spacer.gif"><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" height="32" border="0"></td>
        <td background="/img/spacer.gif" style="color: #717171;font-size: 11px;font-family: tahoma;" align="left">
        ICQ: </td>
        <td background="/img/spacer.gif" style="color: #717171;font-size: 11px;font-family: tahoma;" align="right">
        <a href="" class="quote_btn">цитировать</a> <a href="">изменить</a> 
        <a href="">удалить</a></td>
        <td><img src="/img/spacer.gif" width="5" height="32" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?} ?>
<h2>Добавить ответ</h2>
<?
if(!$_POST['newreply']) {
echo '
<div class="form">
         <form method="post" class="niceform">

                <fieldset>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><label for="comments">Ответ:</label></dt>
                        <dd>
                        <textarea name="newreply" id="my_comment_field" rows="15" cols="43"></textarea></dd>
                    </dl>

                    <dl class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Создать" />
                     </dl>

                </fieldset>
         </form>
</div>

'; 
} else {
 if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$newreply = addslashes($_POST['newreply']); } else {
$newreply = ($_POST['newreply']); }
     @$link = mysql_connect("$hostr", "$userr", "$passwordr");
   if (!$link) {
      die('Не могу соедениться: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    mysql_select_db($dbr);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_unicode_ci'");

$data = date("Y-m-d");
$q = "insert into `proj_detail` (catId, autor, access, message, date) values
   ('$_GET[id]','$_SESSION[login]','$_SESSION[access]','$newreply','$data')";

   $r = mysql_query($q);
   if (!$r) { echo "MySQL error: " . mysql_error()."!"; } else { echo "Сообщение добавлено";}
   echo '<br><a href="index.php?module=projdetail&id='.$_GET['id'].'">Посмотерь категорию</a>';
}
```

Отвечающий за вывод сообщений и добавление участок кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с помощью jQuery:

```
<div>
<div class="your_comment_container">
Тут текст комментария который будет цитироватся
</div>
<div class="quote_btn">Коментировать</div>
</div>
<textarea id="my_comment_field">
</textarea>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".quote_btn").click(function(){
var text_to_quote = $(this).parent().children("div.your_comment_container").html();
$("#my_comment_field").val(text_to_quote)
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: я конечно может что то не понимаю, но не работает(

Comment: Прошу прощения. 
написал $(this).parrent()
а надо $(this).parent()

Comment: а какую имеено библиотеку jquery надо использовать, а то их сейчас очень много наплодилось)

Comment: Возьмите последнюю сборку. 1.6 и выше. 

Под библиотекой я имел в виду сам jQuery, а не сопутствующие плагины.

Comment: скачал, подгрузил, если на дивах делать, див хоть обкликайся, если делать на a href то тоже результата нет.

Comment: Возьмите - подключите библиотеку и просто скопируйте приведенный мной код. 1 в 1. Он работает. Разберитесь как он работает и сможете переделать под себя как вашей душе угодно.

Comment: jquery-1.6.4.js <a href="http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/12/jquery-1-6-4-released/">отсюда</a>, подключил библу, копипаст кода - выводит страницу без ошибок - не работает, див слой не кликабелен. браузер который огненный 3.6.22<br />
Так хорошо.. сделал чистый копипаст на пустой лист, всё ок, но если прописать классы и id в форме, не работает(<br /> могу код вывести если надо. скажем так вариант под конкретный пример. И можно ли как либо иначе, ведь "цитировать" можно было до появления jquery
я надеюсь владельцы портала не против использования тега br /

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, нужно словить выделенный текст и всё, верно? Если так, то поковыряйте доки jquery, уверен что там что-то должно быть!
А если хотите просто по нажатию на кнопочку рядом с комментом добавлять содержимое коммента в форму - то это проще простого, селекторы вам в помощь! Если не разберетесь - приведу схематический код.